# How to apply a function (drop() or.apply) to a DataFrame that is in the value field of a dict

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, apply, geo

I have a `dict` "var_holder3" that in the `values` has the variable names while in the `keys` it has a GeoDataFrame to each variable name. I need to apply a function (getPolyCoords) filled at the same time the field 'x' of the geodataframes is created. The function that needs to be applied is:

```
def getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
     exterior = row[geom].exterior
     if coord_type == 'x':
         return list( exterior.coords.xy[0] )
     elif coord_type == 'y':
         return list( exterior.coords.xy[1] )
```

I try something like

```
for x in var_holder3:
    var_holder3[x]['x'].apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
```

I expected the geodataframes with the new field 'x' but had errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 1415, in __getitem__
    result = super().__getitem__(key)
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'x'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is one of your lines of code *supposed* to have the expression `[x]['x']`? Or is it just supposed to be `[x]`?

Comment: That expression '[x]['x']' is what I thought might be the way to assign the value to the loop 'for' with the first [x] and the name of the field to create with the second ['x']. Recently I just deleted ['x'] and got good results but in series type and do not know how to join it as field in to the geodataframe 'value' of the dict

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it through this for:

```
for x in var_holder3.values():
    x['x']=x.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
    x['y']=x.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)
```

thanks for help